# though i am using classname.this still getting "The constructor Intent(MySampleFragment, Class<Alert>) is undefined" error

Tags: android, android-intent, android-2.2-froyo

This is the part of my code where I am getting the error.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
                  Intent i = new Intent(MySampleFragment.this,Alert.class);
                  startActivity(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getActivity()` or `v.getContext()` instead of `MySampleFragment.this` as first parameter of Intent constructor  as:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),Alert.class);
//Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),Alert.class);
startActivity(i);
```